# NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method: OnDatabaseCallback.insert(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Tags: java

Why does this error come up even though there is definitely a mention of callback?
I keep getting errors about the callback.

Is the onAttach Fragment the problem?

public class NotiFragment extends Fragment {

...

```
OnDatabaseCallback callback;
@Override
public void onAttachFragment(@NonNull Fragment childFragment) {
    super.onAttachFragment(childFragment);
    callback = (OnDatabaseCallback) getParentFragment();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.notifragment, container, false);

    spinner = rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    textView7 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    editText_year = rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText_year);
    editText_month = rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText_month);
    editText_age = rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText_age);
    editText_grade = rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText_grade);
    editText_score = rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText_score);
    savebutton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.savebutton);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (
            getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnersub);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0 :
                    savebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            String year = editText_year.getText().toString();
                            String month = editText_age.getText().toString();
                            String age = editText_grade.getText().toString();
                            String grade = editText_grade.getText().toString();
                            String score = editText_score.getText().toString();
                            callback.insert(year, month, age, grade, score);
                        }
                    });
                    break;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

}

### The interface for OnDatabaseCallback is below.

public interface OnDatabaseCallback {
public void insert(String year, String month, String age, String grade, String score );
public ArrayList selectAll();
}

Comment: Show the stack trace of the exception.  Try stepping through your code with a debugger and looking at the value of ```callback```

Answer (score 0):

There error appears to occur on the line `callback.insert(year,...`.  The variable `callback` is not assigned when the `insert` method is called on it.  The variable `callback` is assigned in the `onAttachFragment()` method but it's not clear from the code you have shown if that method gets called.

Comment: Then can you give me some advice on how to change the code?

Comment: You haven't shown all of your code so I can't tell where the problem is or how you should fix it.  You need to make sure that callback is assigned before it is used.  Maybe you intended to call onAttachFragment() before you call onCreateView() and you forgot to do that.  Or maybe callback should be initialized in the Class constructor.  Or maybe you should have a method called getCallback() that initializes callback before it's used.